# Python 3.9 Supported for Docker images?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

We are using 3.8 python for our docker images AWS. Does docker supports 3.9 for Docker images

Looking into blogs, for latest updates.

Comment: Yes. There's an official `python:3.9` image you can use. `3.11` is the latest official image.

Comment: can you please share me the link if possible?

Comment: Yum install is supported

Comment: Look at the official [Docker Hub Python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python).  I'd expect this is just a matter of changing the version number in your Dockerfile `FROM` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean the `amazon/aws-lambda-python` image, yes, there's a 3.9 tag - [`amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.9`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/amazon/aws-lambda-python/3.9/images/sha256-2381834e9396d038df35a9bd1041d6337ee883897bfc6888bd24dae5f9895c2e).